# Earliest source for "Baruch Hu U'Baruch Sh'mo"

Tags: blessing, sources-mekorot, provenance

What is the earliest source for saying "Baruch Hu U'Baruch Shmo" when hearing someone say the Name of HaShem in a blessing?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9800

Answer (score 13):

The [Tur in Orach Chaim 124](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14265&st=&pgnum=204) says that his father the Rosh would say Baruch Hu U'Baruch Shemo based on the Pasuk [Ki Shem Hashem Ekra Havu Godel L'Elokeinu](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0532.htm#3).

Comment: There is no makor before the Rosh?

Comment: @Yehoshua *before the Tur. In this answer we haven't found this in any of the Rosh's own writings.

Comment: @Yehoshua: This is what I could find. I am open to hearing a earlier Mekor and would delete my answer if someone finds a earlier source.

Comment: @DoubleAA that's another interesting point that it's not in the Rosh's own writings, or nothing that we have a at least.

Comment: @Yehoshua This phrasing seems to fit with *N'chemya* ([9:5](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt35b09.htm)): קוּמוּ בָּרְכוּ אֶת-יְהוָה אֱלֹהֵיכֶם מִן-הָעוֹלָם עַד-הָעוֹלָם וִיבָרְכוּ שֵׁם כְּבֹדֶךָ , and the Tosefta (*B'rachos* 6:22) interprets this verse as providing a guideline for responding to the mention of HaShem's name.

Comment: It is in the Teshuvot ha-Rosh as quoted in the next answer in  the name of the Rosh's father. I  think it is also in the Rokeach.

Comment: @Fred That doesn't seem to be the right makom in tosefta (could a different print though?)

Comment: @Fred in one print I saw it's 6:28

Comment: @Yehoshua I noticed that, too, but too late to change the comment. I recall seeing a reference somewhere to 6:22, though, so I guess there could be a different printing.

Answer (score 10):

It is found in Teshuvas HoRosh ([4:19](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1961&st=&pgnum=30)) in his father's name.

In the [Torah Temimah on Devarim](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14082&st=&pgnum=482&hilite=) (page 480 the last 4 lines of the page) quotes Sefer Chareidim who quotes a Midrash to say ברוך הוא וברוך שמו on every Beracha.

Comment: can you please cite the Rosh at least?

Answer (score 9):

The Rokeach in his commentary to the siddur (פירושי סידור התפילה לרוקח [צד] רצה במנוחתינו) says:

> כשהחזן אומ' ברוך אתה ה' אלקינו ואלקי אבותינו ומתחיל התפילה, הקהל עונים
> ברוך הוא וברוך שמו, ויש אומ' ברוך שם כבוד מלכותו לעולם ועד, ויש אומרים
> יהי שם ה' מבורך מעתה ועד עולם, על כן יזהר הקורא את השם שיזכירו ביראה
> כי כן נאה לו

The source may be from this Midrash (Otzar ha-Midrashim, Heikhalot):

> אמר ר' ישמעאל כל השירות הללו וכל המעשה הזה שמע ר' עקיבא כשירד למרכבה
> ותפס ללמוד אותם מלפני כבודו, שהיו משוררים לפניו משרתיו ברוך הוא וברוך
> שמו, ויברכו את שם כבודך, ומתרומם על כל ברכה ותהלה.

R. Ovadia Yosef (Yechaveh Da'at 4:9) writes that although the Sefer Charedim seems to say that the practice of responding *baruch hu u-varuch shemo* is sourced in the Midrash, this is not what he means; rather it is the Sefer Charedim's own extrapolation to explain the practice of the Rosh:

> ולפע"ד מה שכתב החרדים, מכאן שעונים ברוך הוא וברוך שמו, אין זה מהמדרש,
> (כי מדרש חז"ל הנ"ל הוא מה שאמרו ביומא ל"ז ע"א), ורק מסקנת בעל ספר
> חרדים היא, שמכאן סמך למנהג הרא"ש, וכמו שכתב הטור הנ"ל. ושלא כמשמעות
> דברי היוסף אומץ שהמדרש מחייב דבר זה, שהרי לא מצאנו לשום פוסק שיאמר כן,
> ורק הרא"ש נהג לומר כן, אבל חיוב גמור לענות ברוך הוא וברוך שמו לא
> שמענו.

See also [this](https://www.machonso.org/hamaayan/?gilayon=39&id=1174) article.

Comment: The Rokeach passed away in 1238 and the Rosh was born 1250 or 1259 that makes the Rokeach a contemporary (or just about) to the Rosh's father.

Comment: The Rokeach is still an earlier source, since we don't have the Rosh's father's writings.

Comment: Except he doesn't say the same thing. He says that in one place (after אבותינו in the first bracha of chazarat hashatz) the people would say EITHER בהו"ש or בשכמל"ו.

Comment: Actually he says to say it about everything 2 sections later: כי על כל דבר ודבר שיצא מפי החזן צריכ' יראי השם ית' לומר כמו שאומ' בא"י אמ"ה בתפלה יאמרו הקהל ברוך הוא וברוך שמו וכן על כל דבר ודבר. I quoted the 1st one precisely because it is not exactly the same as our minhag, so that you can see the development

Comment: The extended wording in the Midrash shows an even more obvious [parallel](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31826/earliest-source-for-baruch-hu-ubaruch-shmo#comment82476_31827) to the wording in N'chemya ([9:5](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt35b09.htm)).