# Baruch hu ubaruch shemo - why omitted sometimes?

Tags: halacha, blessing, megillat-esther, shofar

Why is ["Baruch hu ubaruch shemo"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31826/) omitted during the reciting of certain brachot such as meggilah and shofar?

Comment: See this https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/ברוך_הוא_וברוך_שמו which gives some background, where the רא"ש in his teshuvos quotes his father as saying these words upon hearing G-d's name in a bracha - and that this is inferred from words in the gemara Yoma 37a.

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31826/ and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/82220/

Comment: I'm editing out the first half of this post, as it duplicates a previous post, as @Fred points out. The second half stands on its own as a question.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the rule is that once any question has received any answer which received at least a single up vote, edits to the question are not allowed. But, as one of the creators of the site, there are always ways to get in the back door and do workarounds! The reasoning being that it removes the context for earlier answers.

Comment: @YaacovDeane I take exception to the implication of impropriety. I (or the community) could have put the post on hold for containing multiple distinct questions, one of which is a duplicate, and asked the author to make edits. Such edits would be perfectly reasonable and necessary to make the post a good fit for our Q&A model. Any community member could have taken the more helpful route that I did, which is simply making the repair. I don't believe that this invalidates the answer that existed at the time, but if it did, it would be fitting to edit or move the answer.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Please accept my apology if you have taken any offense or been harmed in any way. If memory serves, I believe it was you who pointed that rule out to me years ago when I innocently changed a detail to a question that I had posted once after an answer had been submitted and received an up vote. Only blessings for a good and sweet year…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cases you've raised are cases where someone is saying the *beracha* with someone else in mind, i.e. saying it on their behalf so they don't say it themselves. In fact, it is as if they are actually saying it themself.

Therefore, if they were to say "baruch Hu uvaruch Shemo" it is as if they had said "Baruch Atah Hashem *baruch Hu Uvaruch Shemo* Elokenu Melech HaOlam Boreh Peri Hagefen", which is not the correct way to say the *beracha* (Responsa Devar Shmuel).

This constitues an interruption to the blessing and this is not allowed.

Many great Poskim rule in accordance with the Devar Shmuel. See [this page](https://halachayomit.co.il/en/Default.aspx?HalachaID=3416&PageIndex=57) for more information.

Comment: Thanks. Why do we respond thus during the chazara of 18 ? Isn't that also the ש"ץ saying it for the congregation?

Comment: @Shababnik You are very welcome. there is a machlokes if the repetition is a congregational requirement or not. Those who hold it is do not say _baurch Hu uvaruch Shemo_. See: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/82227/31534. This may also be of interest to you: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/31887/31534

Answer (score 0):

In the context of your secondary question, essentially, you are trying to understand the distinction between ***He*** and ***His name***. That when the response is made, it emphasizes through the connecting letter *Vav* that G-d (אתה, הוא) and His name (יהוה) are one.

Considering the common link between Megillat Esther and blowing the Shofar on Rosh HaShanah which you bring as an example of when we do not answer **blessed is He and His name** in response to reciting a blessing which contains the phrase, ברוך אתה יהוה (meaning blessed are You (G-d transcendent of the aspect of letters and names, *accompanied with G-d's name*), it would seem that those specific blessings which omit our response emphasize the idea of G-d himself מהותו, *at His essence*, which transcends even the level of (the letters of) His name.

There is no usage of any of G-d's names (*none are written*) in Megillat Esther, even though it is understood that the Holy One, blessed be He performed that miracle. The Megillah emphasizes G-d transcendent of all names.

In this sense, it also emphasizes the correlation between Purim פורים, (the day when Megillat Esther is read and Yom HaKippurim יום הכיפורים, (which is referred to as *like Purim*) which concludes with the fifth prayer service of Neilah, which comprises repeated recital of the 13 Attributes is Mercy and the culmination of Teshuvah Shleimah and the transformation of the five Gevurot, (*Gevurah* to *Chesed*) via the five Chassidim. The *red* thread tied around the Altar transforms into a *white* thread.

So too, in regard to Rosh HaShanah, the emphasis of the "sound of the Shofar" (קול שופר) is that the sound, *without letters*, is what introduces the names of G-d (עלה אלהים **בתרועה** יהוה **בקול** שופר).

In practice, the קול שופר, Tekiah (the simple sound, *even without the divisions, meaning the Gevurot which comprise Shevarim and Teruah*,) is both before and after the sounding of שברים-תרועה meaning the Chassidim, Chesed precedes, introduces and surrounds the aspect of Gevurah related to the existence of letters.

That (שברים-תרועה) is the concept of the five Gevurot (מנצפ״ך) which correspond to the five final letters, which according to [Sefer Yetzirah 2:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_Yetzirah.2.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) originate from the five parts of the mouth and give rise to the letters which make up all words and names. That מנצפ״ך is gematria: עולם חסד יבנה ([Tehillim 89:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.89.3?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi)). Like Rambam explains in [Moreh Nevuchim 3:53:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Guide_for_the_Perplexed%2C_Part_3.53.2?vhe=Moreh_Nevuchim,_translated_by_Ibn_Tibon&lang=bi), this pertains to His Middot, which is the source of the concept the Sephirot.

Comment: This does not answer the question

Comment: Fascinating but how does this help us understand why baruch hu ubaruch shemo is omitted from the blessings on megillah and shofar?

Comment: @Dude This should clarify  why the responses are omitted for Megillat Esther and Tekiat Shofar.

Comment: Can this conceptual framework be extended to all the other cases in which people are not supposed to respond BHU"Sh, such as kiddush, havdala, hamotzi, or essentially any other blessing said on their behalf? This answer appears to focus arbitrarily on the two berachot that that happened to be top-of-mind for the asker.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Could this conceptual framework be extended to all other cases? Certainly something worth pondering. But the answer was directed at what was asked, including the particular qualifiers. Perhaps you should pose another question with that more high-gain objective and some kind of exhaustive list of the exceptions. But big, open ended questions create challenges in regard to the site limits on answer length which is more of a Meta issue.

Comment: The general question, which is in fact the one posed, is not an open-ended one. In fact, Rabbi Kaii's answer addresses it clearly, succinctly, and accurately.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Then by all means, you should give his answer your up vote. That’s in keeping with the guidelines for the site which you helped to create. Only blessings for a good and sweet year.